# Como puedo filtrar la actividad de un usuario logueado en Django?

Tags: python, django, desarrollo

Tengo un blog, donde en la parte administrativa tengo un grupo de usuarios llamado 'REDACTORES'. Estos usuarios solo pueden escribir posts, editarlos y nada mas. Me ocurre que los Posts tienen un campo autor, que corresponde a los usuarios registrados en la aplicación. Me pasa que cuando soy superusuario, el campo autor me muestra todos los usuarios que estan registrados en la aplicación. Pero cuando se loguea un usuario de ese grupo, sigue apareciendo la lista de todos los usuarios ya que en realidad no deberia tener la oportunidad de elegir un autor del post, porque es él el que debería ser el único usuario disponible.
Cómo puedo hacer para filtrar en la parte administrativa, la posibilidad de que esto no ocurra ?
Desde ya muchas gracias !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En admin.py debes de declarar el modeladmin a utilizar:

```
class MiModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form.author_creator = request.user
        return form
```

Basicamente este codigo deberia de funcionarte